# When using vcr / cassettes in rspec, is there a way to change match_requests_on per test?

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, specifications, vcr

I'm using vcr in rspec to match save urls and play them back, in the config I'm using the following settings for `match_requests_on` :

`match_requests_on: [:method, :host, :path]`

However I want to modify this config for certain urls only, for example if a url contains `/somepath/` then I want to change the config for this url only to `match_requests_on: [:method, :host, :path, :body]` is there a way to do this in the vcr or rspec config files?

I can't seem to find anywhere that will change it per vcr call globally.

Comment: I have not tried it but, could you please check if this helps in your case - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50651266/2788206

Comment: @MintDeparture You mean like for request `/foo` you want to match on `:method` and `:host` and for `/bar` match `:method`, `:host` and `:body` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to probably go with a custom matcher.

A matcher is just a Proc/lambda called with two params: request_1 and request_2. Responding true when equal, false otherwise.

There's a whole feature describing how to do it: https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/5-1-0/docs/request-matching/register-and-use-a-custom-matcher#use-a-callable-as-a-custom-request-matcher

so what you'd want is

```rb
my_fancy_matcher = lambda do |r1, r2|
case r1.path # IDK if path is a real method, but it's just an example
  when '/foo' 
    r1.parsed_uri == r2.parsed_uri
  when '/bar'
    r1.method == r2.method && r1.parsed_uri == r2.parsed_uri
  else
    false
end
```

and use it directly

```
VCR.use_cassette('hatever', match_requests_on: [my_fancy_matcher]) do 
  ## tests here
end
```

When you get the lambda working as you'd like, and if you're using it everywhere in your specs, you can register it:

```rb
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.hook_into :webmock
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'cassettes'
  c.register_request_matcher :my_fancy_matcher do |request_1, request_2|
    # the logic here
  end
end
```